# Can anyone help to identify this blown MOSFET? Top markings seem to include F50, "ON" in a circle, 3N and "RE4T" in a circle

Tags: mosfet, identification, damage, replacement

I am trying to repair a PCB out of the welder. One of the problems I have found is a blown MOSFET. I have tried searching for a replacement with no luck, as I don't have a complete code. I have posted a picture of the MOSFET and if anyone can identify help it, that would be great.

[image: photo of damaged device on PCB]

Comment: Well, it's made by ON semiconductors.

Comment: Iv tried there website but it's not grate to be honest, I try searching for a MOSFET I had the full code for and I could even find that.

Comment: Any nearby ones with similar codes?

Comment: there are others on the board for the same manfcator but the code on the is laid out in a different formate that don't  line up so there not much use

Comment: If you want to play it safe, you could possibly reach out to their sales or engineering and ask what it is. You would probably provide the serial number and the reference designator of Q26. Worst thing they can tell you is no they won’t do that for you or you would have to purchase another one.

Answer (score 3):

There are several steps that you should be gone through by yourself:

- First of all, I would like to say that the component shown in the image is not necessary be a MOSFET. The only thing that is clear is the package size is either DPAK or D2PAK. Please use Vernier caliper or ruler to identify, with reference of mechanical outline of DPAK and D2PAK from ON Semiconductor website.
- DPAK : https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/369C.PDF
- D2PAK: https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/936A-02.PDF

After decide the package, other information given in the image are "F50", "ON" and "3N". "ON" refers to ON Semiconductor. Then, for the "F50" and "3N", you need search GOOGLE.

- For example, assume that the package size shown in the image is DPAK, and it is manufactured from ON Semiconductor, then the google keywords should be: "F50"  DPAK onsemi and"3N" DPAK onsemi
- "3N" or "F50" mean search engine must find the keywords include "3N" or "F50". In this case, I use keyword: "3N" DPAK onsemi
- Then, the search engine shows variety results. 
  [image: google result for keywords: "3N" DPAK onsemi]
- Clicks the 1st link, make sure the component is made by ON semiconductor and has DPAK package.

[image: 1st link of google results]

- Scroll down to find the marking diagram
  [image: marking diagram]
- Then, maybe this component is a suitable replacement, since it include "3N" on the package
  [image]
- Compared marking diagrams of other choices on GOOGLE.
  [image]
- If still cannot decide, better collect all possible choices and ESAB manual, and passed to ON Semiconductor sales or engineering, as suggested by @KingDuken
- The worst case is you need to purchase a new ESAB, as suggested by @KingDuken

Comment: This is a likely candidate: https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/1/FDD3N50NZ_D-1807162.pdf